# Azure Data Factory - Parameter interpolation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add a pipeline parameter into the body of a post request to an Azure Function app in Azure Data Factory. It appears that the string isn't getting replaced, but the Microsoft documentation suggests I'm doing it the right way. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#request-payload-schema

This is a screenshot of an error I'm getting alongside it:

[image]

I'm confused as to how to proper interpolate pipeline parameters into this request

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), wrap your parameter inside braces `@{pipeline().parameters.ParameterName}`.

Below is the example with my sample API post body:

```
{

            "tourist_name": "@{pipeline().parameters.name}",
            "tourist_email": "@{pipeline().parameters.email}",
            "tourist_location": "@{pipeline().parameters.location}"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Niharika, yes it did solve my issue - thanks very much! :)

Comment: My apologies, already thought I had, thanks again!